# function without argument doesnt work. but why?

Tags: python, lambda, pyqt

i want ask a simple question. i have 2 classes. i got many functions. i keep functions on `class operationsOnFiles()`, and ui elements on class `UI_MainWindow(object)`. i use a `btnSetRandomWallpaper` button call `settingRandomWallpaper()` function with `liste` argument and it didnt work. so i used `lambda` there. then it works.
i tried to do same thing with my other function `updateList()`. it doesnt have any argument. same errors and i used `lambda` there too. no error but no action too. am i missing a point? or something?

```
class operationsOnFiles():
    def settingRandomWallpaper(self, liste):
        super().__init__()
        selectedWallpaper = random.choice(liste)
        os.system("gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri /home/$USER/Projects/src/" + selectedWallpaper)
    def updateList():
        super().__init__()
        Ui_MainWindow.listWidget.addItems(selfish.wallpapers)
selfish = operationsOnFiles()

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        self.btnSetRandomWallpaper.clicked.connect(lambda: selfish.settingRandomWallpaper(selfish.wallpapers))
        self.btnUpdateList.clicked.connect(lambda: operationsOnFiles.updateList)
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: i tried my best. hope i did it well.

Comment: No, that is not an MRE

Comment: TYPO: change to `self.btnUpdateList.clicked.connect(lambda: operationsOnFiles.updateList())` or `self.btnUpdateList.clicked.connect(operationsOnFiles.updateList)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `connect` event is called without parameters. If the target function needs some parameters known at the time the listener is created, you can use a `lambda` to bind that value. If the target doesn't need parameters, you don't need the intermediate `lambda`. In your case the the problem is that you created a `lambda` that just returns the method you want. Minimally it should *call* the method. But since it doesn't need an additional parameter the lambda isn't needed at all.

```
self.btnUpdateList.clicked.connect(operationsOnFiles.updateList)
```

This will expose the next bug in your code, `updateList` needs a self (`def updateList(self):`. And then calling super's `__init__` is really strange.

Comment: i tried your suggestions. it works. and yes, i had to remove that `__init__`. i note your suggestions to my notes. thanks for quick reply and help

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you need to add the parameter `self` to the function.

Then you need to change the command of the ui-element from:

```py
lambda: operationsOnFiles.updateList
```

to:

```py
lambda: operationsOnFiles.updateList()
```